# Use wp_localize_script for non existing script

Tags: wp-localize-script

### Task: What I'm trying to do

I'm fetching data via the [WP Http API](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API) from a remote server. The data I'm getting back is `JSON` encoded. In one of my methods, I'm converting them back and then push it into a class variable, so I can use it later in some scripts.

### Example: How I'm trying to do it

```
// Simplified... please note, that all names/vars/etc. in my class got unique names.
// ...the same goes for the script handler.
class http_api_example
{
    public $remote_data;
    public $response;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->request();
    }

    public function request()
    {
        $request = wp_remote_request( 'http://example.com/HereYouGetSomeJSON' );
        $this->response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request ) );
    }

    public function deliver_to_javascript()
    {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'json_handler', null, array(), null, true );

        // ...then I'm trying to localize it
        wp_localize_script( 'json_handler, 'json_object', array(
             'ajaxurl'    => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
            ,'ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'json_handler_nonce' )
            ,'action'     => 'json-handler-action'
            ,'data'       => $this->response
         )

    }
}
```

---

### Problem: What's not working

> For some reason, I can't access the `json_object` from the console (it works for other objects in other classes just fine).

---

### Debug so far

#### Is it registered and queued?

I tried to take a look if the script is registered:

```
// 'registered': TRUE
var_dump( wp_script_is( 'json_object' ) );

// 'queue': TRUE
var_dump( wp_script_is( 'json_object', 'queue' ) );
```

to be sure, I've also taken a look into the `global $wp_scripts` and can confirm, that it's there.

#### Is it localized?

```
// Data shows up, JSON encoded
var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->registered['json_object']->extra;
```

#### Where in core does it stop?

I went into core and backtraced it the following way:

1. [`wp_localize_script()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_localize_script/) **✓**
2. » [`$wp_scripts->localize()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.1/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php#L130) **✓**
3. »» [`WP_Dependencies: add_data()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.1/wp-includes/class.wp-dependencies.php#L134) **✓**
4. »»» [`WP_Dependencies: add_data()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.1/wp-includes/class.wp-dependencies.php#L134) **<sup>FIN!</sup>**

The **<sup>FIN!</sup>** notes a call to itself. As you can see from the Link to the WP repo on GitHub, inside `->add_data()`, there's another call to `->add_data()` (to itself). I dumped the result and got `TRUE` back.

I'm currently out of "what can I try else?"-options. Maybe someone got an idea, how this is supposed to work or maybe just where I could try to look further.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How does core do it?

After thinking again about it, I thought there [might be a case](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.1/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L342) where WP does the same thing internally. And right: It does it.

#### Example `~/wp-admin/load-scripts.php`

```
$wp_scripts = new WP_Scripts();
wp_default_scripts($wp_scripts);

// inside wp_default_scripts( &$scripts )
$scripts->add( $handle, $src, $dependencies, $version, $args ); // from WP_Dependencies
$scripts->localize( $handle, $object_name, $data ); // from WP_Scripts
```

This means, that there **is a way**, but only with using the internals directly.

So, to add & localize a non-existing file, you just do add `false` instead of `$src`:

```
$wp_scripts->add(
    'your_handle',
    false,
    array(),
    null,
    true
);
$wp_scripts->localize(
    'your_handle',
    "your_handle_object",
    array(
        'ajaxurl'    => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( "your_handle-nonce" ),
        'action'     => "your_handle-action",
        'data'       => array(), // Whatever data you need to transport
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

***Disclaimer**: This doesn't answer my question completely.*

I just found out, that the problem is, that I was using *no* name.

### Half of a solution…

If you're adding *some random* string, then `WP_Scripts/WP_Dependencies/_WP_Dependencies` will give you the desired javascript object.

**Drawback:** If the file doesn't exist, it will still be registered and end in a failed `GET`, which may be responsible for slowing your site down (depending on the timeout).

**Temporary work around:** You can add an empty(!) file, that will load pretty fast and ... do nothing.

### Note

This doesn't answer my question fully, as I'd be pleased to know where to look furhter. WP 3.5 development just started and it is enough time to write a patch/ticket for this... at least if I know where the actual **problem** is. I just can't see a reason, why this only works with a file, when the actual javascript object will be pushed into the global namespace.