# How do I mock HTTP requests for PHPUnit?

Tags: http-api, unit-tests

I'm writing a plugin that makes requests to the Facebook graph API. As I don't want my unit tests to actually make these requests, how would I overcome this? My method calls both `wp_remote_get` and `wp_remote_post`. Searching there does seem to be a way to mock functions using `runkit`, [here](https://github.com/tcz/phpunit-mockfunction)

I want to avoid having contributers requiring too many dependencies so would like to avoid the above method. Is there any other options? My class extends the `WP_UnitTestCase` so I'm hoping maybe there's something from the wp unit-tests that I could use?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you take a look at [`WP_HTTP->request()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http/request/) (which all related functions wrap) it provides a filter hook for the purpose of overriding making a request in favor of returning arbitrary data as response:

```
// Allow plugins to short-circuit the request
$pre = apply_filters( 'pre_http_request', false, $r, $url );
if ( false !== $pre )
    return $pre;
```

Answer (score 3):

In one (two) word(s): Mock Data. PHPUnit got `getMock()` available exactly for that. As the other answers already have perfectly summoned…

- where to get valid mock data (Otto) - make sure you occasionally fetch fresh data
- and where to intercept the data (Rarst)
- and what tools to use (TomJNowell)

…there only (might be) the issue left that your local SSL certificate verification might fail. WP ships with a filter for that:

```
add_filter( 'https_local_ssl_verify', '__return_false' );
```

For any further information about the WP HTTP API, you might want to dig into [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72529/filter-any-http-request-uri/72540#72540), [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/73659/385), [this answer by @Wyck](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60546/use-wp-localize-script-for-non-existing-script) and [this answer by @toscho](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72632/385).

Answer (score 2):

Take the results you get from a valid or invalid request, serialize them into strings, then add code that unserializes the string back into the variable instead of doing the request.

Answer (score 2):

In order to isolate your code further, I would wrap the `wp_remote_get` etc calls in an interface with two implementations. One implementation calls `wp_remote_get`, and the other returns test data.

Using a tool such as runkit in this situation sidesteps the actual problem you have, which is that your code and the APIs are too tightly coupled, and a level of encapsulation and abstraction would be beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

I've had to mock WordPress's HTTP request functions on a few occasions, and so I decided to build a tool for doing that: [WP HTTP TestCase](https://github.com/JDGrimes/wp-http-testcase)

Basically it provides an easy way to do the various things that the other answers have outlined. From the readme:

> ## WP HTTP Testcase
>
> PHPUnit testcase for testing code that uses WordPress's `WP_Http`
>   class.
>
> If you use `wp_remote_request()` or other wrappers for `WP_Http`
>   methods in your code, this makes it difficult to test, especially if
>   the remote server may not be reachable from your testing environment.
>   This testcase solves this by letting you route your requests to a
>   different different host address, use a cached set of responses, or
>   just mock the remote responses by supplying artificial ones.
>
> ## Installation
>
> You can install this package using composer:
>
> `composer require --dev jdgrimes/wp-http-testcase:~1.1`
>
> ## Usage
>
> To use it in your code, you need to first include the
>   `wp-http-testcase.php` file in your PHPUnit bootstrap file. If you
>   will be using the host routing and response caching features, you will
>   need to call `WP_HTTP_TestCase::init()` in your bootstrap file.
>
> Then, in your tests that involve `WP_Http`, you need to extend
>   `WP_HTTP_TestCase` instead of `WP_UnitTestCase` as you normally would.
>
> ### Mocking Responses
>
> #### Using Response Caching
>
> The best way of testing, when possible, it to set up a mock host to
>   handle the requests. In some cases, you may want or need to actually
>   send the requests through to the real server, and that can be done as
>   well. Which of these you do will depend on the nature of the requests,
>   and what side-effects they produce on the recipient host.
>
> Setting Up a Test Host
>
> For example, if you are testing a plugin that makes requests to an API
>   provided by another plugin or other software, you probably don't want
>   or need to test this on a live site. Instead, you can set up a test
>   site, or use a local server that is part of your development
>   environment. There you can install the software that handles the
>   requests. Once this is done, you can run your tests against that test
>   site like this:
>
> `WP_HTTP_TC_HOST=localhost phpunit`
>
> Just replace `localhost` with the hostname of the local server. Note
>   that the `WP_HTTP_TC_*` flags can be defined as PHP constants, or as
>   bash environment variables as above. The latter will take precedence.
>
> Enabling Caching
>
> Of course this will be much slower than most other unit tests, because
>   the requests are bound to take a bit of time. That is where caching
>   comes in. When caching is enabled, the response to each request is
>   cached the first time it is run, and the cached version is used in the
>   future. This means that your tests can remain lightning fast.
>
> To enable caching, just add this to your bootstrap:
>
> `define( 'WP_HTTP_TC_USE_CACHING', true );`
>
> You'll probably also want to specify the directory to save the cache
>   in, via `WP_HTTP_TC_CACHE_DIR`. You can utilize multiple cache groups
>   and switch between them using `WP_HTTP_TC_CACHE_GROUP`.
>
> Using the Live Host
>
> There is the second case though, where you are unable to set up a test
>   server. An example where this would be the case would be if your
>   plugin makes requests to the API provided by GitHub. Depending on the
>   situation, it may be feasible to actually make the requests to the
>   "live" recipient. The main issue again is that the requests will make
>   the tests take a long time to complete. There is also the possibility
>   that the API isn't always accessible from your testing environment, or
>   that your tests will end up pounding the API too hard and you'll get
>   blocked. This is where caching can help you. You only need to run your
>   tests against the "live" API once in a while, and the rest of the time
>   you can test using the cached responses.
>
> #### Supplying Artificial Responses
>
> Of course, there may be times when it isn't possible to create a test
>   server, and it isn't feasible to run against the live server either.
>   In this case, you may want to hard-code artificial responses into your
>   tests. Here is how you can do that:
>
> Before calling the code that will invoke the HTTP request, you need to
>   set the function to mock the responses like so:
>
> `$this->http_responder = array( $this, 'mock_server_response' );`
>
> The HTTP responder function will be passed two arguments, the request
>   arguments and the URL the request was intended for.
>
> ```
> protected function mock_server_response( $request, $url ) {
>    return array( 'body' => 'Test response.' ); 
> }
> ```
>
> For a full list of the `$request` and response arguments, see
>   [`WP_Http::request()`](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http/request/#source-code)